# How can I get a complete version from TortoiseHg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg as my source control for developing a CMS project written in .NET/C#. I don't know how can I get a whole complete version from my source repository. Is it possible? a version for a specified date.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "whole complete version" mean?

Comment: I mean if I can get a version which has all of files prior to my specified date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `hg update` will update your working directory to any prior version of your choice.

The command `hg archive` will provide you with a zipfile or tarball representing any point in history.

For both commands you can specify your exact revision using the `-r` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, Can i specify a date for getting the version?

Comment: The `hg update` will take a `-d` date argument.  If you want to do the same thing with `hg archive` you'll want to do the `hg update` first and the `hg archive` without a `-r` will do the working directory, which is what `hg update` will set.